# Secure way to save the local credentials?

Tags: network, radius, tacacs, aaa

In the network administration world, normally we configure the network devices to use an AAA server (Radius or tacacs+). As a backup, in case the AAA server is not reachable, we configure the network device to use its local database (local username and password).

I am looking for a way to manage the local credentials for the network devices. Any suggestions?

Comment: Password manager?

Comment: May be with support for multiple user

Comment: Yes, I figured that. There are password managers for teams. Some are enterprise ready, like CyberArk.

Comment: I want to be able to access my devices in case of aaa failure using the local device credentials, so I need password management solution and I am wondering if there is something more specific for network access

Comment: Yep. Clearer. And yep: enterprise password managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enterprise password managers** offer you the ability to store these types of things in a central store for admins to use.

You can restrict access, log when people request credentials, and some interface directly with the device and change the credentials once used or act as a 'wrapper' so you ssh through the password system in order to get to the end device.

Lots of options. A quick vendor search will reward you with rich results.